# Rails survey app with multiple users logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently working with 2 colleagues on a survey app, and we are almost completed, however we have run into something I would imagine is a common issue.

Essentially, when one user interacts with the survey, this action is carried out for all other others. IE John hits next, Mary hits next and Mary ends up skipping a question. This is obviously not what we want. We want to separate the question objects from eachother, or tie them to the account, or create them for each of the account objects to allow for multiple users to interact with the survey at once and their actions/answers to be mutually exclusive. Is there some usual way of doing this in rails, or what is that even called? Any linked material is much appreciated.

```
class QuestionsBasicController < ApplicationController

@@a = 0

def index
    @b = @@a
    @userprojid = current_user.project_id
    @@compid= QuestionsBasic.connection.select_all("SELECT company_id FROM project WHERE ID ="+@userprojid.to_s)
    @@compid= @@compid.rows[0][0]
    @result = QuestionsBasic.connection.select_all("SELECT questiontxt FROM questions_basic WHERE company_id="+@@compid.to_s)
    @@fanarray = @result.rows
    @anarray = @@fanarray
end


def next
    @@a += 1
    @b = @@a
    @anarray = @@fanarray
    render "questions_basic/index"
end

def previous
    if @@a <= 0
        @@a = 1
    end
    @@a -= 1
    @b = @@a
    @anarray = @@fanarray
    render "questions_basic/index"

end
```

User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

    has_many :answers_basics, :class_name => 'AnswersBasic'
    has_many :answers_basics, :class_name => 'AnswersBasic'
    has_many :answers_basic_anies, :class_name => 'AnswersBasicAny'
    has_many :answers_basic_anies, :class_name => 'AnswersBasicAny'
    has_many :answers_tmps, :class_name => 'AnswersTmp'
    has_many :answers_tmps, :class_name => 'AnswersTmp'
    has_many :answers_tmp_anies, :class_name => 'AnswersTmpAny'
    has_many :answers_tmp_anies, :class_name => 'AnswersTmpAny'
    has_many :user_anies, :class_name => 'UserAny'
    has_many :user_anies, :class_name => 'UserAny'
    belongs_to :project, :class_name => 'Project', :foreign_key => :project_id
end
```

Comment: How does the system know who John and Mary are?  Are they registering?

Comment: Their accounts are set up by an admin. I'm using the devise gem. Right now they are just dummy accounts we plugged in manually.

Comment: The survey should have a user_id then.  You need to persist that back-and-forth between controllers and views.  Please edit your question to show some code.

Comment: There is the questions controller. We have user_id attributes from the SQL table, or do you mean an extra attribute?

For our application we are having a feature at the end to change any answers given by the user, hence loading the array with question objects from the table, not just accessing them via SQL each time. I guess it's ORM.

I also put up the user model.

Comment: Still with me John?

Comment: Yes.  What about the view?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123620/discussion-between-john-feltz-and-noel-murphy).